# BouncyCastle Parameter Object Not a ECParameterSpec

Tags: java, security, encryption, bouncycastle, java-security

I am using EC for encryption using bouncycastle,

BC Jar: org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.59

and Using the below code to initialize the `KeyPairGenerator`

```
ECNamedCurveParameterSpec parameterSpec
                    = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");

System.out.println("Passing ParameterSpec => " + parameterSpec);
System.out.println("Is Instance of org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec => " + (parameterSpec instanceof ECParameterSpec));

KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator
                    = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(parameterSpec);
```

But this is giving me the below exception.

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: parameter object not a ECParameterSpec
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyPairGeneratorSpi$EC.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyPairGenerator.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:411)
        at io.gupshup.crypto.web.ECKeyGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyGenerator.java:56)
```

Now the code in the BouncyCastleProvider checks the instance of the class that I have sout'ed  before initializing. Also I have printed all of the classes loaded in the process. I am not being able to Identify the issue with my code.

For Reference this is the output of sout and class loader.

```
[Loaded org.bouncycastle.util.Pack from file:/opt/tomcat0.8/webapps/inbox/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar]
Passing ParameterSpec => org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECNamedCurveParameterSpec@7e5f0eee
Is Instance of org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec => true
[Loaded org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyPairGeneratorSpi from file:/opt/tomcat0.8/webapps/channel/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar]
[Loaded org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyPairGeneratorSpi$EC from file:/opt/tomcat0.8/webapps/channel/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar]
[Loaded org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyPairGeneratorSpi$ECDSA from file:/opt/tomcat0.8/webapps/channel/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar]
[Loaded org.bouncycastle.crypto.KeyGenerationParameters from file:/opt/tomcat0.8/webapps/channel/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar]
[Loaded org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECKeyGenerationParameters from file:/opt/tomcat0.8/webapps/channel/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar]
[Loaded org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator from file:/opt/tomcat0.8/webapps/channel/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar]
[Loaded org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.ECKeyPairGenerator from file:/opt/tomcat0.8/webapps/channel/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor150 from __JVM_DefineClass__]
[Loaded sun.security.jca.JCAUtil from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.security.jca.JCAUtil$CachedSecureRandomHolder from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECNamedCurveGenParameterSpec from file:/opt/tomcat0.8/webapps/channel/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

Please help me on the same as I am not being able to find the issue, I have tried the same code in my local setup and things are working as they should.

This is the code within the SPI that is not working for some unknown reason.

```
if (params == null)
{
    ECParameterSpec implicitCA = configuration.getEcImplicitlyCa();
    if (implicitCA == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidAlgorithmParameterException("null parameter passed but no implicitCA set");
    }

    this.ecParams = null;
    this.param = createKeyGenParamsBC(implicitCA, random);
}
else if (params instanceof ECParameterSpec)
{
    this.ecParams = params;
    this.param = createKeyGenParamsBC((ECParameterSpec)params, random);
}
else if (params instanceof java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec)
{
    this.ecParams = params;
    this.param = createKeyGenParamsJCE((java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec)params, random);
}
else if (params instanceof ECGenParameterSpec)
{
    initializeNamedCurve(((ECGenParameterSpec)params).getName(), random);
}
else if (params instanceof ECNamedCurveGenParameterSpec)
{`initializeNamedCurve(((ECNamedCurveGenParameterSpec)params).getName(), random);`
}
else
{
    throw new InvalidAlgorithmParameterException("parameter object not a ECParameterSpec");
}
```

TIA

Comment: This may be a dependency issue, where you have 2 bouncycastle versions on your classpath, and where the parameterspec class is loaded from the other jar.

Comment: there is only one bouncycastle provider jar

Comment: EC used for encryption... any specific scheme you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

The Bouncy Castle *provider* uses the JCA defined API for the parameter specifications. If you would want to use the named curve secp256k1 then you should indicate it using the JCA class `ECGenParameterSpec`:

```
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    ECGenParameterSpec namedParamSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
    KeyPairGenerator ecKPGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "BC");
    ecKPGen.initialize(namedParamSpec);
    KeyPair ecKP = ecKPGen.generateKeyPair();
```

---

Of course, if you need Bouncy Castle for that is debatable, although the new EC code in Bouncy is performing pretty well.

Anyway,

```
    ECGenParameterSpec namedParamSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
    KeyPairGenerator ecKPGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
    ecKPGen.initialize(namedParamSpec);
    KeyPair ecKP = ecKPGen.generateKeyPair();
```

works pretty well on my system.

Comment: It is working in my system... But not in the server... No way to identify the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems java Security.addProvider() will cause classloader leaks. Then it will result instanceof return false.It can simplely sloved as follows:

```java
  private static KeyPairGenerator g

  static{
    try {
       cleanEnvAndInitG(CURVE_NAME);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
       Random r = new Random();
       //sleep 30ms~300ms
       int time= r.nextInt(300-30+1) + 30;
       Thread.sleep(time);
       cleanEnvAndInitG(CURVE_NAME);
       logger.info(e.getMessage(), e);
    }catch( ...
 }
    public static void cleanEnvAndInitG(String curveName) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        Security.removeProvider(ECDH_PROVIDER);
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(curveName);
        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ECDH_ALGORITHM, ECDH_PROVIDER);
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
    }
```

Attention:

1）You should design retry mechanism when initialize failed to avoid concurrent problem.

2) If possible you should cache g to improve performance.